# Time complexity of checking all pairwise comparisons in a list

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I would like to rank three items: $\{s,t,r\}$. Clearly there are $n!$ possibilities, and for each possibility, ie: if I have 
$s < t < r$, then this implies: $s < t, s < r, t < r$.  Over all there seems to be $n^2 n!$ comparisons to be made.

Now suppose I measure the likelihood of a ranking with:

$Pr[s < t < r] = Pr[ s < t ] Pr [s < r] Pr[t < r],$

where the equality sign comes from the independence assumption of the problem. So again our sample space has $n!$ samples then to find the most likely ordering I would need to check n! samples, which is prohibitively expensive.

So the question is is there an algorithm to compute this value with lower complexity?

Comment: Do you mean ranking $n$ items?

Comment: yup all n items

Comment: But why are you saying you are ranking three items?

Comment: sorry in my specific case I let n = 3.